# Need to copy 2 keys out of object and put it in parent object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to manipulate an array of objects. It's a big tree as you u can see below.

I want to get both key value of `la` and `ld` at the zero index of the `products` array and put them beside `c` (in the `dop` array).

Please find my codepen link in comments not sure why I am unable to share code pen link here

```
const arr = [
  {
    a: 1,
    dop: [
      {
        c: 3,
        //la: 11,
        //ld: 33
        products: [
          { ld: 11, la: 33 }, // <--- zero index
          { ld: 233, la: 44 } // <--
        ]
      },

      { d: 4, e: 4 }
    ]
  },

  {
    a: 1,
    dop: [
      {
        c: 3,
        //la: 11,
        //ld: 33
        products: [
          { ld: 11, la: 33 },
          { ld: 233, la: 44 }
        ]
      },

      { d: 4, e: 4 }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Please do not post pictures of code and try to keep the examples here  at SO

Comment: There is a reason SO does not allow links to codepen and jsfiddle without code here

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: What you've tried so far? any approach to your needs? In order to help you you have to add some snippet with your code

Comment: Codepen.io/feizel/pen/porqaBO

Answer (score 0):

move or copy?

Here I copy

```js
const arr = [{ a: 1, dop: [{ c: 3, products: [{ ld: 11, la: 33 }, { ld: 233, la: 44 } ] }, { d: 4, e: 4 } ] }, { a: 1, dop: [{ c: 3, products: [{ ld: 11, la: 33 }, { ld: 233, la: 44 } ] }, { d: 4, e: 4 } ] } ];

arr.forEach(item => Object.assign(item.dop[0],item.dop[0].products[0]))
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: #mplyngjan please check the code pen link in my comment your code is giving undefined value

Answer (score 0):

Using `map` and destructuring

```js
const process = (data) =>
  data.map(({ dop, ...rest }) => {
    return {
      ...rest,
      dop: dop.map(({ products, ...dopRest }) => {
        const [{ ld, la }] = products ?? [{}];
        return {
          ...dopRest,
          ld,
          la,
          products,
        };
      }),
    };
  });

const arr = [
  {
    a: 1,
    dop: [
      {
        c: 3,
        //la: 11,
        //ld: 33
        products: [
          { ld: 11111, la: 11111 }, // <--- zero index
          { ld: 233, la: 44 },
          { ld: 233, la: 44 },
          { ld: 233, la: 44 },
        ],
      },

      { d: 4, e: 4 },
    ],
  },

  {
    a: 2,
    dop: [
      {
        c: 3,
        //la: 11,
        //ld: 33
        products: [
          { ld: 222222, la: 222222 }, // <--- zero index
          { ld: 233, la: 44 }, // <--
        ],
      },

      { d: 4, e: 4 },
    ],
  },
  {
    a: 2,
    dop: [
      {
        c: 3,
        //la: 11,
        //ld: 33
        products: [
          { ld: 333333, la: 3333333 }, // <--- zero index
          { ld: 233, la: 44 }, // <--
        ],
      },

      { d: 4, e: 4 },
    ],
  },
];

console.log(process(arr));
```